# Alfresco copy the space name to space title

Tags: alfresco

I had 500 folders below the top level directory...
I want to copy the space name to space title..based on the title am doing some more customization in the below directories...

what are the ways to achieve it...

Please help me

regards,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is creating a script.

First, you should go to the space "Company Home/Data Dictionary/Scripts". There, using the create content wizard, create a new plain text file named "rename.js", with the following code:

```
for (var i=0;i<companyhome.children.length;i++){    
    var child=companyhome.children[i];
    child.properties.title=child.name;
    child.save();
}
```

Next step, go to "Company Home", open "More Actions/View Details", and select "Run Action". Choose the action "Execute an script", select the script "rename.js", and click on "Finish".

In a few seconds, you should have the title of all elements changed.

Comment: You would also want to check if it's folder: if (child.isContainer) {...}